# Performing operations on a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I need to write a function that will multiply the quantity of each item with its price, combine the total of each, and then divide that sum by the total number of items.
`[(3.99 * 1 + 1.99 * 3 + .99 * 3 + 2.99 * 1 + .75 * 9) / 17]`

```py
shopping_cart = {
    "tax": .08,
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "orange juice",
            "price": 3.99,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "rice",
            "price": 1.99,
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "title": "beans",
            "price": 0.99,
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "title": "chili sauce",
            "price": 2.99,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "chocolate",
            "price": 0.75,
            "quantity": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

I've written the code below but I'm encountering 2 issues. 1) When I test the portion that multiplies the item quantity with its price, I get 0's for each result. 2) Once that part is solved, I don't know how to hold off on dividing by the total quantity (17), until after all the complete running total is calculated.

```py
def get_average_spent_per_item(d):
    RunningCombinedItemTotal=0
    for i in d['items']:
        RunningCombinedItemTotal += ((i['price'] in d['items']) * (i['quantity'] in d['items']))
        return RunningCombined total / (len(d['items']))
```

**#this last line should only run after the full amount of `RunningCombinedItemTotal` is calculated**

I've read through tons of material but when it comes to working with nested dictionaries, all I can find is material on how to create them but not how to operate on them. If anyone knows of any material that covers this I'd like to review it.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, `for i in d['items']:`, `i` will be one element at a time in your list of dicts.

```
def get_average_spent_per_item(d):
    RunningCombinedItemTotal = 0
    TotalQuantity = 0
    for i in d['items']:
        RunningCombinedItemTotal += i['price'] * i['quantity']
        TotalQuantity += i['quantity']
    return RunningCombinedItemTotal / TotalQuantity
```

Part of the reason you were seeing zeros is that you're actually multiplying boolean values unintentionally. The `x in y` is a boolean. When you start doing math/multiplication, those values are treated as integers: True is 1, False is 0. You're booleans are False, so you're getting zeros for the products. Remove the `in y` part like I show above to get the proper values.

As for the final value, you want to sum the quantities inside the loop. Then, when you're done with the loop, you can use the sum to divide the running total, as shown above. It's easiest to create a new variable for that running quantity sum.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest splitting the code up into more variables/lines to make it more readable. Please note below how I do so.

```
def get_average_spent_per_item(d):
    total_items = 0
    total_price = 0.0

    for item in shopping_cart['items']:
        quantity = item.get('quantity', 0)
        price = item.get('price') * quantity
        total_items += quantity
        total_price += price

    return round(total_price / total_items, 2)

get_average_spent_per_item(shopping_cart)
>> 1.33
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when you put `i['price'] in d['items']`, it returns a boolean. You should simply put `i['price']`. Secondly, to get the number of items, you should use `sum([elt['quantity'] for elt in d['items'])`.

Answer (score 0):

When using `(i['price'] in d['items'])` were you intending to use a list comprehension iteration?

We can get all the prices with list comprehension:

```
In [4]: [i['price'] for i in shopping_cart['items']]                                                                 
Out[4]: [3.99, 1.99, 0.99, 2.99, 0.75]
```

and multiply by the quantity with:

```
In [5]: [i['price']*i['quantity'] for i in shopping_cart['items']]                                                   
Out[5]: [3.99, 5.97, 2.9699999999999998, 2.99, 6.75]
```

and sum those:

```
In [6]: sum([i['price']*i['quantity'] for i in shopping_cart['items']])                                              
Out[6]: 22.67
```

and the total quantify:

```
In [7]: sum([i['quantity'] for i in shopping_cart['items']])                                                         
Out[7]: 17
```

This approach does require a double iteration, once for the weighted sum, and once for the count.  So the explicit for loop that you use might be better (in which case you don't need the `in` step, as others point out).

A more compact version of that double comprehension (don't need to make lists):

```
In [57]: sum(i['price']*i['quantity'] for i in shopping_cart['items'])/\ 
    ...: sum(i['quantity'] for i in shopping_cart['items'])                                                          
Out[57]: 1.333529411764706
```

===

A way to get both quantity and weighted price with on `items` loop:

```
In [34]: g = ((i['price']*i['quantity'], i['quantity']) for i in shopping_cart['items'])                             
In [35]: list(g)                                                                                                     
Out[35]: [(3.99, 1), (5.97, 3), (2.9699999999999998, 3), (2.99, 1), (6.75, 9)]
```

but to get a sum on these, we have to first 'transpose' the tuples (with `zip(*)`:

```
In [36]: g = ((i['price']*i['quantity'], i['quantity']) for i in shopping_cart['items'])                             
In [37]: list(zip(*g))                                                                                               
Out[37]: [(3.99, 5.97, 2.9699999999999998, 2.99, 6.75), (1, 3, 3, 1, 9)]
In [38]: sum(_[0])/sum(_[1])                                                                                         
Out[38]: 1.333529411764706
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mean() function from the statistics module and feed it the list of individual item prices.

```
from statistics import mean
m = mean(items["price"] for items in shopping_cart["items"] for _ in range(items["quantity"]))

print(m) # 1.3335294117647059
```